# Is there a way to change 'project' once a bug has been entered in MantisBT?

Tags: bug-tracking, mantis

As evident from title, I entered a bug in MantisBT but mistaken choose wrong project. I can go back and edit most of the parameters of bug but it doesn't allow me to change the project. I looked in configuration and there seems to be no option for that there as well. Is there a way I fix the bug information by changing the project to the correct value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can move issues between projects if your system configuration and access levels allow it (look for the *Move* button in the *View Issue Details* page)

Answer (score 1):

You can also move multiple issues by doing the following:

- Go to View Issues page.
- Filter on the issues you want to move (optional)
- Tick the issues from the list that you want to move or select all.
- Go to the bottom of the list and select "Move" then click Go.
- Select project to move to.

Note that since MantisBT uses a universal id across all projects, moving an issue doesn't break links to it, since URL to the issue will remain the same.